# Spring integration ftp adapter is failed to poll files from a ftp server

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I have a web application that is doing a polling to a ftp server via spring integration ftp adapter. The basic idea is to fetch every new file on server to local. It runs just perfect on my Windows pc. Once a new files updated on ftp server, the adapter will fetch it to local directory. However, the ftp adapter stops working when the application is running on a Linux server. It gives no error or exception in log but all debug messages from filter of ftp adapter are missing from the log file.

Here is `applilcationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="N/A"/>
    <property name="username" value="N/A"/>
    <property name="password" value="N/A"/>
    <property name="port" value="1"/>
</bean>

<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
    remote-directory="/" local-directory="/tmp/" filter="fileFilter" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" 
        task-executor="pollerPool" max-messages-per-poll="1000" fixedrate="15000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="pollerPool" pool-size="5" keep-alive="30" queue-capacity="10000" />
```

The file filer is defined as:

```
public List<FTPFile> filterFiles(FTPFile[] files) {
    logger.debug("\nFiltering ftp file...");
    List<FTPFile> result = new LinkedList<FTPFile>();
    if (localFolder != null) {
        for (FTPFile file : files) {                
            // download files with specific identifier
            if (SpreaderFileUtil.checkByIdentifiers(file.getName(), externalIds)) {
                // now check whether this file should be download or not
                if (SpreaderFileUtil.isDownload(file.getName(), localFolder)) {
                    result.add(file);
                } 
            }
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("Local folder is NULL, cannot filter for any files ");
    }
    return result;
}
```

I add a logger in filer for debugging. The debugging message shows when application is running on local pc but disappears when it runs on server. I check the ftp connection and it is OK. On server I succeeded to build a ftp connect to remote server and to fetch a file manually. I don't have any clue how to proceed because there is no error or exception at all in log. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you have logging configured correctly? If using log4j you can use `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to verify.

Comment: The server may override your logging reference. Tipically any EE server do that prefering the logging configuration via its management tool, like WebSphere Admin Console or JBOSS `logging.xml`

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your comments. Well, log4j is working pretty well, I think. A file appender thresholds log message with a higher level than DEBUG. In case the log4j somehow doesn't work as well as I expected, I didn't get any files from ftp server but the fact is at least three files are supposed to be fetched.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Actually I would say the log4j is not the matter as only the log message from filterFiles method is missing and any other debug loggers works good.

Comment: So, may be you have a bad FTP connection setting on the server? Or there is no netwrok access from that Java server to the FTP server...

Comment: Hi Artem, I tried connecting to that ftp server and manually fetching a file to local. The connection was pretty stable. I launch the application on tomcat locally and on server in same time, new files have been synchronized to local directory but server received nothing. It seemed like ftp adapter is disable somehow on server side.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I come to close this suspending stream. The trick in my previous Spring-integration project was client mode. Right below is the reference doc.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/AbstractFtpSessionFactory.html#setClientMode-int-
The fact is the default client mode is set to Active when defining a DefaultFtpSessionFactory. My problem was solved by setting client mode to Passive mode.

Comment: In the event that you are connecting to a SFTP, the latest version of Spring Integration (4.3.4 at the time of writing) does not allow you to set a ClientMode for DefaultSftpSessionFactory. I have successfully connected to an FTPS using the DefaultFtpsSessionFactory instead which DOES allow you to set a Passive ClientMode. Thanks Shawn.X.Du!